# Помогите с ботом (telebot и vk_api) на python

Tags: python, telebot, vkontakte-api

Приветствую уважаемые знатоки! Хочу написать бота для телеграмма на python. Суть бота в том что я отправляю боту ссылку с **acces token'ом**, бот извлекает от туда токен и используя библиотеку **vk_api** выведит мне в inline-кнопках все чаты (группы) аккаунта вк. С извлечением токена это просто, но вот как сделать так что бы бот мне мои чаты (группы) вывел в inline-кнопках ?

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)